# docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity

Tags: docker, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying docker with linux subsystem installed using wsl.While docker run I am getting below error.

```
docker run -p 9411:9411 openzipkin/zipkin:2.23

docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint optimistic_ellis (234ghjd36f3189be43cea490a29466a0499eb0ddc62f39gfrdgg898776666666222):  (iptables failed: iptables --wait -t nat -A DOCKER -p tcp -d 0/0 --dport 9411 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:9411 ! -i docker0: iptables: Invalid argument. Run `dmesg' for more information.
 (exit status 1)).
ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

when I tried dmesg

```
ptuser@IN-XXXXXXX:/mnt/c/Users/ptUser$ dmesg
[    0.024561]  Microsoft 4.4.0-19041.1237-Microsoft 4.4.35
[    0.085971] <3>init: (1) ERROR: ConfigInitializeCommon:665: Failed to mount /usr/lib/wsl/drive
[    0.085975] : 19
[    0.086041] <3>init: (1) ERROR: ConfigInitializeCommon:665: Failed to mount /usr/lib/wsl/lib
[    0.086044] 19
[    0.438663] <3>init: (1) ERROR: UtilCreateProcessAndWait:501: /bin/mount failed with status
[    0.438676] 2000
```